# How to get size of disk driver sector

Tags: c, linux, assembly, hard-drive

Can get size of disk sector via the Linux API/ABI? It's about the quantum of I/O disk, normally it's equal 512 bytes, but others values can be too (usually multiple 512 bytes).
Also it should not confuse to size of logical block or to size of sector of a file system.

A block device is reflected as file in a file system of an UNIX (/dev/sda, /dev/sr etc.) It means, can open that file and make some manipulations to its content like with content of the corresponded block device.

So specifically the work to a true block device similar the work to a virtual hard disk (the .vhd format for instance).
But i don't know how to get size of sector in general case.
At moment  i've single solution: get the maximal CHS address and size of hard drive, both action via BIOS. But i think, it's bad idea, because portability lost

Comment: A `stat` system call (e.g. on `/dev/sda`) will give you an IO Block size of 4096.  But always reports 4096 for me, even on old disks with a 512-byte physical sector size.  `smartctl -a /dev/sda` will report the 512-byte sector size on old disks; not sure exactly what it uses.  If you have a .vhd, the optimal I/O block size depends on the filesystem it's stored on, not anything about the disk image file itself.  Fake CHS geometries from the BIOS (especially a BIOS in a VM) are almost certainly irrelevant.

Comment: SATA has commands to ask the disk what its physical and logical block sizes are.